# Inherit same variable but different name

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is there a classy c-way (other than simply setting a variable equal to)(pun intended) to inherit a variable from a class with a different name than in the base class? In python there is the `as` keyword for aliasing things, is there such method in c++?

ie:

```
class special_type_of_grid
{
    protected: double** special_grid;
    public: special_type_of_grid();
}
class integrator: protected special_type_of_grid
{
    private: /*grid alias special_grid*/
    public: void integrate(){
        //...
        sum += grid[i][j]*h;
        //...}
}
```

so that there can be more than one 'special type of grid'.

I guess an okay way to do this would be a pointer initialized in the constructor, but can it be done in the private/public scope?

Comment: What counts as "classy"?

Comment: Why would you need to? Doing so would break encapsulation, derived classes should only interact with the parent class' members via accessors provided by the parent class.

Comment: Why do you want to have such a feature?  It seems like it would just create confusion because the same type hierarchy would be referring to the same value via different names.

Comment: I'm trying hard to understand the *pun*. Please help me.

Comment: You may create a variable of reference type pointing to the parent's variable. It's strange intention, though

Comment: @user396672: However, that prevents the implicit generation of assignment operators, and (probably) increases the class size; so you probably don't want to.

Comment: @Nawaz its punny because classes are classy (not actually funny, but that's okay :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ provides no ways to do it. However, there is a possibility to do it someway, but it a **very** bad style.

```
class Base {
    int x;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() : y(x) {
        // ctor code here
    }
private:
    int& y;
};
```

This example shows that you can do a lot of strange things with C++, but if you think that this is the only solution than you have a bad design somewhere else. Furthermore, you should add `: y(x)` to ALL `Derived` ctors.

A better (and more OOP-style) solution is to use getters/setters.

```
class Derived : public Base {
    int& y() { return x; }
};
```

Or even better:

```
class Derived : public Base {
    int getY() { return x; }
    void setY(int value) { x = value; }
};
```

However, this may cause confusion and misunderstanding for someone who will read your code.

Comment: It does look pretty bad, but can you explain how to use the :y(x), or how it works?

Comment: @user1888743 That means that when you construct Derived object than x is passed to y's constructor. That should be done because references have no default constructors.

Comment: @user1888743 It's the syntax introducing a "member initialization list", and it's the only way to initialize `y` (with `x` here) since it's a reference (you cannot do `Derived() { y = x; }`).